Flutter Text inside a container, RenderFlex overflowed by pixels on the right
Hey I can't figure out a way to fix the Text inside of a container that it will break the line and expand the container by itself. I already searched for solutions but Expanded and Flexible don't work. Can anyone help me? :)
Here's a picture of the problem:

myContainer({required String title}) {
 return Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5.0),
  child: SizedBox(
      child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
    child: GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        print("Das hat funktioniert");
      },
      child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: const Color.fromRGBO(86, 89, 94, 1),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
            border: Border.all(
              color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 128, 0, 1),
              width: 2,
            ),
          ),
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10),
          child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Row(children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: 12.0, top: 14, bottom: 14),
                    child: Container(
                      child: Text(
                        title,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 22,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ])
              ])),
    ),
  )));

Thanks so much!

Try to replace second Row with Expanded.

This question is similar to: How to solve "A RenderFlex overflowed by 143 pixels on the right." error in text?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on Stack Overflow, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the CC BY-SA 4.0 license for Stack Overflow to distribute that content. By Stack Overflow policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know how to delete your post, take a look at
How does deleting work?

You can dissociate a question from your account, instead of vandalizing:
If you made a post that you regret posting you can have the post dissociated from your account

Add your Text widget inside Expanded:
Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5.0),
      child: SizedBox(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              print("Das hat funktioniert");
            },
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: const Color.fromRGBO(86, 89, 94, 1),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 128, 0, 1),
                  width: 2,
                ),
              ),
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Row(children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                              left: 12.0, top: 14, bottom: 14),
                          child: Container(
                            child: Text(
                              'Add your long title here after Expanded it does not give any type of error',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 22,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ]),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),

Result: 

Thank you so much! I just added 1 Expanded, that was the mistake.

Most Welcome, Enjoy your ride with Flutter
